# Shorthand for just $(document) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I noticed in the jQuery docs that as of 1.4, calling $() with no args just returns an empty set rather than $(document). http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#returning-empty-set

So, is there no other shorthand for $(document)?

I ask because I can't decide which is uglier if I'm trying to select an element by an ID that I have in a variable: $("#" + myID) or $(document).find(myId).

Thanks.

Comment: If `myId` just contains the ID and not a `#`, then `$(document).find(myId)` won't work.  It would need to be `$(document).find('#'+myId)`.  Also, I don't think `$('#'+myID)` is ugly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You always can make your own alias:

```
$d = $(document);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are selecting an element by an ID you should use `$("#" + myID)`. `$(document).find(myId)` would be wrong.

Comment: What's the difference? I thought that was effectively the same thing.

Comment: As mentioned by Rocket, if your id variable doesn't include '#' in the beginning, it won't work. For eg. `var myId = "#" + id;` will work, but `var myId = id;` will not work with `$(document).find(myId)`.

Comment: Note `$(document).find('#'+myId)` is just as good as `$('#'+myId)` other than being longer.  Both will work.